# ¿Cómo inspeccionar elemento usando Safari Browser?

Tags: safari

Tengo un caso interesante para analizar, la aplicación web que desarrollé funciona de maravilla en los navegadores móviles: Firefox, Google Chrome, sin embargo al visualizar la aplicación en Safari en un iPhone, por alguna razón toma demasiado tiempo. Tengo que entrar en modo Sherlock Holmes, debuggear y resolver el caso; me doy con la sorpresa que Safari no tiene el legendario F12. Quizás esté en modo ninja y lo tiene oculto en algún lado. ¿Saben cómo mostrarlo o si se tiene que pagar una app del AppStore para acceder a ello?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elemental mi querido Watson, en Safari, el clásico inspeccionar elemento está en modo ninja, lo tienes que habilitar de la siguiente manera:

En la barra de menu, click en Safari > Preferences > Advanced tab.

Marcar el check: "Show Develop menu in menu bar"

Ahora sí, en la página click derecho, inspect element.